# A polynomial's coefficients are non-negative integers, $f(1)=6$ and $f(7)=3438$. What is the value of $f(3)$?

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Here is the question:

A polynomial $f$ is given. All its coefficients are non-negative integers, $f(1) = 6$ and $f(7) = 3438$. What is the value of $f(3)$?

And here is the solution:

We do not know the degree of the polynomial, so let it be n.

$\therefore f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + a_{n-2} x^{n-2} + ... + a_0$

$f(1) = a_n + a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + ... + a_0 = 6$

Since all the coefficients are $ \geq 0 \implies a_i \leq 6 \;\forall i \leq n$

$f(7) = a_n7^n + a_{n-1}7^{n-1} + a_{n-2} 7^{n-2} ... + a_0 = 3438$

Since all coefficients $a_i \leq 6 \;\forall i \leq n$, this is the base expansion of the number 3438.

So all we need to do is keep dividing by 7 and observe the remainders :

$3438 = 7 \cdot 491 + 1 \implies a_0 = 1$

$491 = 7 \cdot 70 + 1 \implies a_1 = 1$

$70 = 7 \cdot 10 + 0 \implies a_2 = 0$

$10 = 7 \cdot 1 + 3 \implies a_3 = 3$

$1 = 7 \cdot 0 + 1 \implies a_4 = 1$

$\therefore f(x) = x^4 + 3x^3 + x + 1 \implies f(3) = 166$

I don't understand the process that they used, and what "base 7 expansion" is and why they use it. Someone please explain. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So regrading the question you have in their solution :

Let me explain in such a way : a 3 digit number in base 10 (what we use currently : the decimal representation) is expressed as $a 10^0 + b 10^1 + c 10^2$ where you may know a,b,c < 10 and non negative. That is the number is cba.

For example, $123 = 1 \cdot 10^2 + 2 \cdot 10^1 + 3 \cdot 10^0$

You may notice that the greatest possible 3 digit number is 999, i.e. all a,b,c can only be uptil 9 (one less than number 10 - the base)

Since in the solution they established that **coincidentally** all $a_i \leq 6 \;\forall i \leq n$ and because of the fact that f(7) is in such a manner (the sum of powers of 7 multiplied by some number < 7), it can strike you that you can use the base 7 to express a number 3438(in the same way as mentioned above for base 10) which would be in the format $a 7^n + b 7^{n-1} + c 7^{n-2} ...$ and if $a 7^n + b 7^{n-1} + c 7^{n-2} ... = f(7) = a_n 7^n + a_{n-1} 7^{n-1} + a_{n-2} 7^{n-2} ... \implies a = a_n, b = a_{n-1}, c = a_{n-2}$ (this can be proved)

The next steps are just converting a base 10 number into base 7 number which you should look up [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Base_conversion).

I am posting another answer which is the same as converting the base to 7 but kind of an explanation of how that works :

So this answer is taking inspiration from the comment by Dávid Laczkó :

As you correctly established, all non negative integral coefficients are $\leq 6$

So using that fact and using $f(7) = 3438 =  a_n 7^n + a_{n-1} 7^{n-1} + ... + a_0$

Because all coefficients are non negative and $\leq 6$ $a_0$ is not a multiple of 7 but $a_n 7^n + a_{n-1} 7^{n-1} + ... + 7 a_1 = 7\cdot(a_n7^{n-1} + a_{n-1}7^{n-2} + ... + a_1)$ is a multiple of 7 because $(a_n7^{n-1} + a_{n-1}7^{n-2} + ... + a_1)$ is an integer

So we must have $3438 - a_0$ as a multiple of 7 where $a_0 \leq 6 \implies 3438 - a_0$ is the closest 7 multiple to 3438 which is 3437

$\therefore a_0 = 1$

So we get $7\cdot(a_n7^{n-1} + a_{n-1}7^{n-2} + ... + a_1) = 3437 \implies a_n7^{n-1} + a_{n-1}7^{n-2} + ... + a_1 = 491$

Again by the same apporach, $7 \cdot (a_n7^{n-2} + a_{n-1}7^{n-3} + ... + a_2) = 491 - a_1$

So $491-a_1$ is the closest 7 multiple to 491 which is 490.

$\therefore a_1 = 1$

So we get $7 \cdot (a_n7^{n-2} + a_{n-1}7^{n-3} + ... + a_2) = 490 \implies a_n7^{n-2} + a_{n-1}7^{n-3} + ... + a_2 = 70$

Again we get $70 - a_2$ is the closest 7 multiple to 70 which is 70 itself

$\therefore a_2 = 0 \;\&\; a_n7^{n-3} + a_{n-1}7^{n-4} + ... + a_3 = 10$

Again we get $10 - a_3$ is the closest 7 multiple to 10 which is 7

$\therefore a_3 = 3 \;\&\; a_n7^{n-4} + a_{n-1}7^{n-5} + ... + a_4 = 1$

Now since all coefficients are non negative, $a_4 = 1$ is he only possible case $\because 7 \cdot (a_n7^{n-5} + a_{n-1}7^{n-5} + ... + a_5)$ is a multiple of 7 and the only multiple of 7 closest to 1 (and non negative becuase as mentioned, all cofficients are non negative) is $0$.

And now $\because a_n7^{n-5} + a_{n-1}7^{n-5} + ... + a_5 = 0 \;\&\;$ all coefficients are non negatuve, they will all have to be 0. So, because $a_n = 0 \;\forall n \geq 5$ we can ignore $a_5, a_6 ...$

So finally we get $f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + ... + a_0 = x^4 + 3x^3 + x + 1$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $p$ is a positive integer, $M\in\Bbb N$ and
$$M=\sum_{k=0}^na_kp^k=\sum_{k=0}^nb_kp^k$$
such that
$$a_k,b_k\in\{0,1,...,p-1\}\tag1$$
Then
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(a_k-b_k)p^k=0\tag2.$$
From $(2)$, we have $a_0-b_0\equiv0 \pmod p$ which implies that $a_0=b_0$ because of $(1)$. Now assume that $a_k=b_k$ for all $k<i.$ Then from $(2)$ we have $(a_i-b_i)p^i\equiv 0\pmod{p^{i+1}}$ which implies that $a_i=b_i$ because of $(1).$ By induction $a_k=b_k$ for all $k$. Therefore, there is a unique polynomial $f(x)$ whose coefficients are in $\{0,1,...,p-1\}$ and $f(p)=M.$

Now let $p=7$ and $M=3438.$